# Polars Rust: Read json file like Data Fusion or Spark?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

How can I read a JSON file with `polars`, with the following format:

```
{<json object>},
{<json object>}
```

I can read the same file in DataFusion as follows:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> datafusion::error::Result<()> {
    env_logger::init();
    let start = Instant::now();
    let file_path = "datalayers/landing/Toys_and_Games_5.json";
    // let file_path = "datalayers/landing/test_file.json";
    let df = read_data(file_path.to_string()).await?;
    let duration = start.elapsed();
    info!{"Pipeline executed successfully!"}
    info!("Pipeline Execution time: {:?}", duration);
    Ok(())
}

async fn read_data(path: String) -> datafusion::error::Result<Arc<DataFrame>> {
    let mut ctx = SessionContext::new();
    let selected_columns = vec![
        "asin",
        "vote",
        "verified",
        "unixReviewTime",
        "reviewTime",
        "reviewText",
    ];
    let df_ = ctx.read_json(path, NdJsonReadOptions::default()).await?;
    let df_ = df_.select_columns(&selected_columns)?;
    info!("Data loading plan created successfully!");
    Ok(df_)
}
```

The spark code is quite similar. The only reference I found for polars in old API documentation with JsonReader and [Cursor](https://docs.rs/polars/0.2.1/polars/frame/ser/json/index.html). But it does not show how to read data from file. The File in the example can be downloaded with wget as follows:

```
wget -P datalayers/landing http://deepyeti.ucsd.edu/jianmo/amazon/categoryFilesSmall/Toys_and_Games_5.json.gz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [latest polars as of 2022](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/index.html) You have to make sure that `"json"` is added as to the `feature` in `[dependencies]` in Cargo for polars. For example,

```ini
[dependencies]
polars = { version="0.24.2", features = ["lazy", "json"] }
tokio = { version = "1.21.1", features = ["full"] }
```

Now for reading line-separated json (I know there is an official name but it escapes me right now) into a dataframe:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() -> PolarsResult<()> {
    let schema = Schema::from(vec![
        Field::new("reviwerID", DataType::Utf8),
        Field::new("asin", DataType::Utf8),
        Field::new("reviewerName", DataType::Utf8),
        Field::new("helpful", DataType::List(Box::new(DataType::Int32))),
        Field::new("reviewText", DataType::Utf8),
        Field::new("overall", DataType::Float64),
        Field::new("summary", DataType::Utf8),
        Field::new("unixReviewTime", DataType::Int64),
        Field::new("reviewTime", DataType::Utf8),
        Field::new("style", DataType::Utf8),
    ]);
    let df = match LazyJsonLineReader::new("Toys_and_Games_5.ndjson".into())
        .with_schema(schema)
        .finish() {
        Ok(lf) => lf,
        Err(e) => panic!("Error: {}", e),
    }
    .collect();
    println!("{:?}", df);
    Ok(())
}
```

The output is:

```
Ok(shape: (3695, 10)
┌───────────┬────────────┬──────────────────────────┬─────────┬─────┬──────────────────────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────┬───────┐
│ reviwerID ┆ asin       ┆ reviewerName             ┆ helpful ┆ ... ┆ summary                          ┆ unixReviewTime ┆ reviewTime  ┆ style │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---                      ┆ ---     ┆     ┆ ---                              ┆ ---            ┆ ---         ┆ ---   │
│ str       ┆ str        ┆ str                      ┆ i32     ┆     ┆ str                              ┆ i64            ┆ str         ┆ str   │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪══════════════════════════╪═════════╪═════╪══════════════════════════════════╪════════════════╪═════════════╪═══════╡
│ null      ┆ 0486427706 ┆ Ginger                   ┆ null    ┆ ... ┆ Nice book                        ┆ 1381017600     ┆ 10 6, 2013  ┆ null  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null      ┆ 0486427706 ┆ Dragonflies &amp; Autumn ┆ null    ┆ ... ┆ Great pictures                   ┆ 1376006400     ┆ 08 9, 2013  ┆ null  │
│           ┆            ┆ Leaves                   ┆         ┆     ┆                                  ┆                ┆             ┆       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null      ┆ 0486427706 ┆ barbara ann              ┆ null    ┆ ... ┆ The pictures are great, I've     ┆ 1459814400     ┆ 04 5, 2016  ┆ null  │
│           ┆            ┆                          ┆         ┆     ┆ don...                           ┆                ┆             ┆       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null      ┆ 0486427706 ┆ Samantha                 ┆ null    ┆ ... ┆ So beautiful!                    ┆ 1455321600     ┆ 02 13, 2016 ┆ null  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...       ┆ ...        ┆ ...                      ┆ ...     ┆ ... ┆ ...                              ┆ ...            ┆ ...         ┆ ...   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null      ┆ B00IEOH8KO ┆ A. Red                   ┆ null    ┆ ... ┆ Made party decorating easy and   ┆ 1453939200     ┆ 01 28, 2016 ┆ null  │
│           ┆            ┆                          ┆         ┆     ┆ a...                             ┆                ┆             ┆       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null      ┆ B00IEOH8KO ┆ nilda morales            ┆ null    ┆ ... ┆ Four Stars                       ┆ 1452988800     ┆ 01 17, 2016 ┆ null  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null      ┆ B00IEOH8KO ┆ W. Ross                  ┆ null    ┆ ... ┆ Five Stars                       ┆ 1449014400     ┆ 12 2, 2015  ┆ null  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null      ┆ B00IEOH8KO ┆ Liz89                    ┆ null    ┆ ... ┆ Great Deal                       ┆ 1431129600     ┆ 05 9, 2015  ┆ null  │
└───────────┴────────────┴──────────────────────────┴─────────┴─────┴──────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────┴───────┘)
```

#IMPORTANT NOTE

Notice that I had to explicitly provide the schema because the `"style"`  column in your data-set is completely weird, which means that polars has difficulty inferring it.  If you fill out the complete schema it should work, so I didn't bother creating a Struct for it, however you can go ahead and do that if you like :).